# Is there a way to pass variables from template to helper

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

I was wondering whether there is a way to pass variables from templates to template helper functions.

I've got a few nesting loops but no way of knowing which data i'm looping.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add what tech you are working with.

Answer (score 3):

Yes (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers):

> Helpers can accept positional and keyword arguments:
>
> ```
> Template.myTemplate.helpers({   
>   displayName: function (firstName, lastName, keyword) {
>     var prefix = keyword.hash.title ? keyword.hash.title + " " : "";
>     return prefix + firstName + " " + lastName;   } });
> ```
>
> Then you can call this helper from template like this:
>
> ```
> {{displayName "John" "Doe" title="President"}}
> ```

If beyond that you would like to use data from the template's current data context as argument to the helpers, you can do that, too, of course. For example, if the current data context includes `firstname`, `lastname` and `title`:

```
 {{displayName firstname lastname title=title}}
```

This is handy in an `#each` loop, for instance. And if you don't know what's in your current context, then just use `console.log(this)` inside the helper function and you'll see the complete data context on your console.